# Servlet redirect error/ jsp cannot load css

Tags: html, jsp, redirect, servlets, response.redirect

I'm having some issues to redirect to an HTML page via servlet.

I have an index.jsp and index.htm page in the same directory.

When i use the following code my servlet redirects to the jsp page fine, but if i change it to index.htm i cannot redirect and get this error on the browser (mozilla)

*"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."*

```
response.setHeader("Location", "/portal/index.jsp");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
```

The reason I want to redirect to the htm page instead of jsp page is because when i redirect to the jsp page, none of my css gets loaded..which is a whole other problem itself.

I have been spending some days now trying to find a solution but I am not getting anywhere. If anyone has any advice to either of the issues i will be so greatful. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

1. The below url takes you to the question in mozilla support forum where it has a solution to what you are facing.
   [Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1113004)
2. For CSS in JSP: If you're using an external CSS file and including in JSP using link href="", make sure the relative path of the CSS file provided in the JSP file is correct.

Another way to redirect is using response.sendRedirect("...")

Answer (score -1):

You can used

response.sendRedirect("pangename.jsp");

RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("pagename.jsp");

rd.forward(request, response);